# how to consume custom spring-boot-actuator metrics

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I've got a use case where I need to keep track of processing time metrics for a given component and use that as a feedback loop for tuning purposes within my spring-boot application. I thought I'd use a custom metric via an autowired GaugeService in the component I need to monitor, which is working fine and I can see my metrics in the /metrics endpoint. What I'm having trouble with is how to consume those metrics in application code. I would ideally like to receive every gauge submit result and compute a weighted moving average. Is this not a good use case for spring-boot-actuator metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the metrics information via code should be quiet possible via Injecting `MetricsEndpoint` bean into your application code as usual we inject anyother bean.

`MetricsEndpoint` bean is defined by `EndpointAutoConfiguration`.

Every `Endpoint` defines [`@ReadOperation`, `@WriteOperation`, `@DeleteOperation`] annotated method in order for that end point to be adapted by exposing technology like JMX, Spring webflux etc.

In your case you may be only interested in calling the `@ReadOperation` of [MetricsEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/MetricsEndpoint.html) which means two method : `listNames` or `metric`. See the given link for more information.

Now when/how often you call this endpoint depends on you only.

Hope this helps.